# Jquery Upload with Jquery Form plugin - Not getting response

Tags: jquery, forms, response

I'm trying to use Malsup Jquery Form Plugin to make an image uploader, the thing is that i'm not getting response from the validation.

On the validation i do multiple checks and then I print a number of error to get it with jquery and print a message that corresponds to this number (I'll put the php validation code at the end of the post.)

If I do this:

```
   $("#formCrearCategoria").ajaxForm({
        beforeSend: function(){},
        uploadProgress: function(){},
        success: function(){},
        complete: function(response){
            $(".success").html(response.responseText);
        }
    });
```

I don't get anything, so, response.responseText is empty.

**Note: If I use the upload form without Jquery Form plugin (redirecting to the action file) It works.**

The php validation code is:

```
<?php
spl_autoload_register(function($nombre){
    include_once("../../classes/".$nombre.".php");
});
include_once("../../functions/info.php");

// I check with a boolean to not desorganize all, with multiple if that makes it 0 if it doesn't check the condition.
// At the end I check if todoOk is true, and if it is it means that is ready to go.

$todoOk = 0;

if(isset($_POST["submit"]) && isset($_POST["nombreCategoria"])){
    $cCategoria = new Categoria;
    $todoOk = 1;
    $nombre = $_POST["nombreCategoria"];
    if($_FILES["imagenUpload"]["tmp_name"] != ""){ // File upload is not empty...
        $fileDir = "uploads/";
        $dirAndName = $fileDir . md5(basename($_FILES["imagenUpload"]["name"])) . "." . pathinfo($_FILES["imagenUpload"]["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $fileTarget = "../" . $dirAndName;
        $imageFileType = pathinfo($_FILES["imagenUpload"]["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $urlImagen = getUrl() . "admin/" . $dirAndName;

        $check = getimagesize($_FILES['imagenUpload']['tmp_name']);
        if($check == FALSE){
            $todoOk = 0;
            echo "0";
        }else{
            if($imageFileType !== 'jpg' && $imageFileType !== 'png' && $imageFileType !== 'jpeg'){
                $todoOk = 0;
                echo "00";
            }else{ // It passed through the image file checks, so I upoad it.
                if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES["imagenUpload"]["tmp_name"], $fileTarget)){
                    echo "001";
                }
            }
        }
    }else{ // File input is empty...
        $urlImagen = getUrl() . "images/default/thumbnailRect.png";
    }

    // Chequeo si nombre existe...
    $encontro = $cCategoria->selID($nombre);
    if($encontro){
        echo "000";
        $todoOk = 0;
    }elseif ($todoOk) {
        $db = new MyMysqli;
        $consulta = $db->consulta("INSERT INTO categorias(nombreCategoria,imagenCategoria) VALUES ('".$nombre."','".$urlImagen."')");
        if($consulta){
            echo "1";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

**Solved !**

The problem was that in the php validation I ask if isset($_POST['submit']), and, for some reason, submit is not set when it validates via jquery form plugin.

Cheers !!